# Spring MVC 4 with mvc:resources not working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, pom.xml, tomcat8

I was trying to make a simple JAVA web application using Spring MVC. I tried to add CSS and JS files insides my resource folder which is located at `/Webcontents/resources/ and webcontents/JS` respectively. Accordingly I need to make some configuration in my `servlet.xm`l and include spring-webmvc inside this file. My `servlet.xml` is shown below :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.webrtc.controller" />

 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
 </bean>
 
</beans>
```

My POM.xml is given below :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebRTCProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebRTCProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Once I build the project using Maven and try to run it on server using Tomcat which is added on Eclipse IDE, I am getting following errors :

> ```
>     SEVERE: Context initialization failed
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
> ```
>
> Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for
>   element [resources]
>       Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webrtc-servlet.xml]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.fatal(FailFastProblemReporter.java:60)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:68)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.fatal(ReaderContext.java:55)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.findDecoratorForNode(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:121)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.decorate(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:99)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1448)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1435)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.decorateBeanDefinitionIfRequired(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1415)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.processBeanDefinition(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:301)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:190)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:169)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:613)
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
>         at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1099)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:989)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

My other confiurations are as below:

Windows 10

Eclipse IDE

Spring 4.3.7

JAVA SDK 1.8

Tomcat 8.5

I tried different solutions to fix the issue like versioning issues, changing `servlet.xml` file etc but could not able to solve the issue.

Anyone knows how can I solve this issue ?

Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated! In case you need more details about project I will be able to provide you more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My servlet.xml is shown below

The configuration `/WEB-INF/webrtc-servlet.xml` has errors. Either remove
this file or fix errors there.

And these elements should be outside the bean definition

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

Comment: Hi! You mean do I have some syntax error in my file which I posted ? Or some configuration errors ?

Comment: Just changing the position of <mvc:resources > by putting it outside the <bean> definition solved the issue! Thank you so much

Comment: You should accept and upvote the answer. If you don't know how to do that see https://stackoverflow.com/tour